# View disappers when editing begins

Tags: ios, swift3

i am moving my view up when the keyboard appers using :
in view will appear :

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CommentsView.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

and a function :

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
        viewToMove.frame.origin.y -= keyboardHeight
        print(keyboardHeight)
    }
}
```

it works fine but the moment i start writing in the keyboard the view i just moved up disappears and i have not idea why
can anyone help me in this matter ?
the problem occurs both on simulator and on a physical device

Comment: When keyboard open then text field view is up on keyboard?

Comment: @Jay yes when the keyboard is opened the text field view is up on the keyboard , but the moment i type something on the keyboard the text field view disappears .. any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: implement textfield delegate method or not?

Comment: yes already did ..

Comment: in textfield change charcter method you which code write send me.

Comment: i am not using any action method for textfiield .. thats why i am wondering why is this happening ..